# How to get cgi input variables in the same order as they come in?

Tags: python, post, cgi, paypal-ipn, server-side-scripting

I have a simple listener in python awaiting a http post request:

```
import cgi
import sys

inputVars = cgi.Fieldstorage()
f.open('test','a')
f.write("how they come in: "+ str(inputVars))
```

The variables come in as I can see here in a particular order. e.g.

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('payment_type', 'instant'), MiniFieldStorage('payment_date', 'Wed Jun 29 2016 17:16:32 GMT 0200 (CEST)'), MiniFieldStorage('payment_status', 'Pending')])
```

but when i cycle through the FieldStorage to get the data into a list, the order of the data is a different one:

```
for item in inputVars:
    f.write(item)
    f.write("\n")
```

writes (example):

```
payment_status
payment_type
payment_date
```

how do I get these in the exact same order as they arrive in the POST? The API (paypal-ipn) needs me to return a modifies version of the data in the exact order as it came in.

I could cut up the string and build my own parser, but that seems a bit too hacked for that kind of problem.

Comment: If you look at definition of the `Fieldstorage` class in the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/cgi.py) of the `cgi` module, there's references to `self.list` which looks like it might contain what you're looking for.

Comment: thx for answering. sadly i am too much of a oop-idiot to understand where these referneces are pointing to.

Comment: i found another solution through this post: http://flyingspaniel.blogspot.de/2014/12/do-frameworks-get-in-way.html
still would be great to understand how i could achieve this with cgi.Fieldstorage. Gonna read through cgi source as recommended by @martineau

Comment: In that case now would be a great time to learn more. If you look at where `self.list` is referenced in the class code starting at line 352, you'll see that if it's not `None`, it's a list containing either `MiniFieldStorage` or `Fieldstorage` instances. I can tell this because those are the only things ever `append()`ed to it. Both of those classes have `name` attribute which you should be able to print out and see what order they are in. You can also look and see how `self.list` is used in other parts of the code, like the `__len__` and `__contains__` methods. The code also has good comments